# Add the term slug as a class to the product category div tag in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

In Woocommerce, I'm trying to filter the output of `wc_get_product_cat_class()` function located in `wc-template-functions.php` core code:

```
function wc_get_product_cat_class( $class = '', $category = null ) {
    $classes   = is_array( $class ) ? $class : array_map( 'trim', explode( ' ', $class ) );
    $classes[] = 'product-category';
    $classes[] = 'product';
    $classes[] = wc_get_loop_class();
    $classes   = apply_filters( 'product_cat_class', $classes, $class, $category );

    return array_unique( array_filter( $classes ) );
}
```

I need it to add the cat slug as a class to each li tag on the category page.

It works fine when i edit the file directly and add this to the function :

```
$classes[] = $category->slug;
```

I then have `<li class="product-category whatever-cat-slug product">`

But obviously i am trying to find a better way to add it to my themes function file.

I have tried this, without success :

```
add_filter( 'product_cat_class' , 'add_class_to_category_list_element');
function add_class_to_category_list_element($classes) {
$classes[] = $category->slug;
return $classes;
}
```

Because `$category` has no meaning here.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: you can access `$category` parameter from your filter function, it is passed along (see [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)) increase your accepted arguments and get `$category` parameter in your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `product_cat_class` filter hook manage 3 arguments `$classes`, `$class` and `$category`, so your code is just a bit incomplete. Also you should be sure that `$category` is a defined object before trying to get the slug on it.

Try this instead:

```
add_filter( 'product_cat_class' , 'add_class_to_category_list_element', 10, 3 );
function add_class_to_category_list_element( $classes, $class, $category ) {
    if( is_object( $category ) )
        $classes[] = $category->slug;

    return $classes;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.